# IdentityServer4: Custom ISigningCredentialStore to generate dynamic signing key based Token result

Tags: identityserver4

In **IdentityServer4** I am implementing a custom `ISigningCredentialStore` because I need to generate different keys dependent of some content in `TokenResult`. I am also implementing a custom `ICustomTokenRequestValidator` in which I am adding a custom client claim.

What I need is to generate a signing key based on the value of the claim that is being added in my implementation of `ICustomTokenRequestValidator`. Any idea?

Comment: Since ISigningCredentialStore.GetSigningCredentialsAsync() doesn't take any arguments and the public part of the credential used needs to be exposed via the discovery endpoint I'm not sure how you'll achieve this. The spec pretty much demands that your signing and validation credentials be static.

What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: Thank you @mackie. Basically this is a odd scenario that I need to accomplish to be compatible with legacy systems. So I have a few apps (clients) that are multi-tenant. Each tenant has its shared signing key (HS256). Now we are trying to build an isolated auth server based on IdentityServer. So, I need to provide a signing key that is unique for the tenant of the request.

Comment: I don’t think that is possible without really altering how the framework works. The purpose of the signing stuff is just so a client can verify that a JWT really was issued by the authority.

Comment: Please add some of the code you've tried. I am hoping to implement this same interface, would like to see some examples.

Comment: @codeMonkey I didn't achieve what I wanted to accomplish initially. The interface ISigningCredentialStore was very simple by that time, and you would only need to implement the method GetSigningCredentialsAsync(). I don't know if IdentitiyServer has evolved since then and if the interface is still the same.